# Array passing to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

When passing the values of an array into a function, the C++ compiler
only passes the name of the array (address where the array begins) into
the function. Explain why the C++ compiler only passes the name of an
array into a function and not the entire contents of the array?

Comment: An explanation of why the language is defined this way would be a treatise on the history of computing in general and programming languages in particular, which is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The "why" is simple. Because that's what the standard says.

[[§4.2 ¶ 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array#1)]

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
>   temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. The
>   result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

[[§8.3.5 ¶ 5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5)]

> A single name can be used for several different functions in a single
>   scope; this is function overloading (Clause [over]). All declarations
>   for a function shall agree exactly in both the return type and the
>   parameter-type-list. The type of a function is determined using the
>   following rules. The type of each parameter (including function
>   parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and
>   declarator. **After determining the type of each parameter, any
>   parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be
>   “pointer to T”.** After producing the list of parameter types, any
>   top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when
>   forming the function type. The resulting list of transformed parameter
>   types and the presence or absence of the ellipsis or a function
>   parameter pack is the function's parameter-type-list. [ Note: This
>   transformation does not affect the types of the parameters. For
>   example, `int(*)(const int p, decltype(p)*)` and `int(*)(int, const int*)`
>   are identical types.  — end note ]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incorrect. When you write

```
int foo[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
f(foo);
```

you're not passing the name of `foo` to function `f`, you're passing a pointer to the first element of `foo`. Function `f` knows it's getting an `int*`, and it knows how big an `int` is, so it knows how far ahead in memory to look for the second, third, fourth etc elements. This is the barest minimum to implement arrays, which is why it was popular.

In C++11, to pass an array which knows how big it is, use `std::array`. This is an array which knows how big it is:

```
#include <array>
std::array<int, 5> foo {1,2,3,4,5};

f(foo);

foo[42] = 1; // compile-time error!
```

However you need to write `f` such that it knows how big `array` is:

```
void f(const std::array<int, 5>& ai); // this works
```

or make it templated, so it can take any size array:

```
template<size_t Size>
void f(const std::array<int, Size>& ai);
```

(or even an array of any type:)

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
void f(const std::array<T, Size>& a);
```

Alternatively, store data in `std::vector`s. They're sometimes less efficient than `std::array` or built-in arrays, but a lot more flexible:

```
std::vector<int> foo {1,2,3,4,5};
f(foo);

...

void f(const std::vector<int>& foo);
```